# What are CourseCompletions and when are they created?

Tags: desire2learn

I see the entries in the API documentation for getting "CourseCompletion" objects. But do not see how these are entered in the Learning Environment. Can you explain what these objects are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CourseCompletion` records are essentially meta-data type notes that you can attach to a user/course-offering combination to make a record of a user having "completed" a course on such-and-such a date. The course completion record can also carry an expiry date for when the "completion" becomes out of date or no longer relevant. These features are not heavily used by D2L customers, and are not exposed through the Web UI.

I don't believe there is any automation within the back-end service around the creation or modification of these records (for example, there isn't an event in the system when a course completion record would get created: a client would need to manually create such a record when it wants one to exist).